# Angular2: servicing an id param route with observables

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I'm trying to route my app based on the angular2 tutorials with the modification of keeping all my data in JSON files. After a lot of trial and error I've gotten to this last point but I can't figure out how to setup a route with and id variable while using observables. From what I've seen all the tutorials use promises which is unavailable because I routed my original data with a observable.

The problem I'm having right now is I'm mapping my object in my services like so `.map(projects => projects.find(project => project.id === id));` and then I'm trying to run a .subscribe in my compent like this

`getProject(this.route.snapshot.params['id'])
.subscribe(project => this.project = project);`

I'm getting and error in Typescript saying `project does not exist on type` which I believe means it is not being defined in my component. But all of the examples I'm looking at do not have their "project" defined in component either. Again they are using promises and I'm trying to use observables so obviously something is a muck with my own code.

I'm still trying to wrap my head around observables I have a hunch I shouldn't be running a .map in my service but I'm not sure what I'm supposed to do instead.

gallery.component

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute, Params } from '@angular/router';
import { Location }                 from '@angular/common';

import { Project } from '../project';
import { ProjectService } from '../project.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'gallery',
  templateUrl: './gallery.html',
  styleUrls: ['./gallery.scss'],
  providers: [ProjectService]
})

export class GalleryComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(
    private projectService: ProjectService,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private location: Location
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.projectService
      .getProject(this.route.snapshot.params['id'])
      .subscribe(project => this.project = project);
  }
}
```

project.service

```
import { Injectable }     from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable }     from 'rxjs/Observable';

import { Project } from './project';

@Injectable()
export class ProjectService {
  private projectsUrl = 'data/project.json'; // URL to web API

  constructor(private http: Http) { }

  getProjects(): Observable<Project[]> {
    return this.http.get(this.projectsUrl)
      .map(this.extractData)
  }

  getProject(id: string): Observable<Project> {
    return this.getProjects()
      .map(projects => projects.find(project => project.id === id));
  }

  private extractData(res: Response) {
    let body = res.json();
    return body.project || {};
  }
}
```

Comment: _"But all of the examples I'm looking at do not have their "project" defined in component either."_. They're probably not _complete_ examples. You need it.

Comment: Is the way I'm trying to implement ngOnInit() correct? I thought this.project might be passed through my service.

Comment: Yeah it looks fine

Comment: hmm upon further inspection the project.id seems to be passing fine. The project object is not. I really only need the id so that isn't an issue. I'm just wondering why I'm getting this error and what code I don't need to remove it.

Comment: `projects.find` will return an array, not a single object. Maybe that has something to do with it

Comment: thanks I'll look into it.

Comment: I am not sure if you figure this out already because you mentioned it in your question: you need to declare `project` in your component. I believe the error is in `ngOnInit`: `this.project = project`... "this.project" doesn't exit.

Comment: yeah the error I was getting was `project doesn't exist` and it was triggered under this.project. I wasn't sure and still am a little uncertain why the error is being triggered. As @peeskillet pointed out, I think it has something to do with how I'm requesting the ID in my service. My mind is failing me right now and I haven't found the answer. Hopefully tomorrow when I'm fresh I can work through this! Thanks guys for your input.